# How to specify local Flutter version (e.g. an older release)?

Tags: flutter

I would like to test my application / package running on an older version of Flutter, e.g. specifically Flutter v2.2.3.

There are 2 commands, `flutter upgrade` and `flutter downgrade` which might seem to be relevant, but how do I select the specific version of Flutter I want to use? `flutter upgrade --help` and `flutter downgrade --help` do not provide any extra information.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Recommended (**git**): Just checking out a specific commit in the Flutter repo

- Change directory to your flutter installation folder, e.g. `/opt/flutter`.
- `git checkout` the git tag (change to the branch pointed by the tag). For example, there is a git tag called `2.5.0` for the version `2.5.0`, so run `git checkout 2.5.0`. (Thanks Eugene :) )

  - Or alternatively, if I want version 2.5.0, I can get the commit SHA (ref) from the [Flutter SDK releases](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos) page. That website says the `ref` for  `2.5.0` is `4cc385b`. At the flutter installation directory, run `git checkout 4cc385b`.
- Then in the terminal, run `flutter` (or any specific flutter command) to download and build this version of flutter.

### Using [**FVM** (Flutter version Management)](https://fvm.app/)

- You also specify the specific version of Flutter using FVM, e.g. `fvm use 2.5.1`

### Download the specific version of Flutter from [Flutter SDK releases](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos) and install it.

- This is the slowest way, as you would have to download the entire repo again.

Comment: you can also run "git checkout 2.5.0" from the flutter folder. To check all available versions just run "git tag". Also to find the Flutter installation folder run "flutter doctor -v"

Answer (score 4):

## Using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

1. Find the cask of the version you want to install `homebrew-cast` git history: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/commits/master/Casks/f/flutter.rb
2. Click on the icon for "View at this point in history"
3. Click on Raw
4. Copy the URL from your browser.

   Example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/b029783b06b38177c7e3b36ca824789d516468c1/Casks/f/flutter.rb
5. `brew install --cask https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/b029783b06b38177c7e3b36ca824789d516468c1/Casks/f/flutter.rb`
6. Check `flutter --version`

Comment: you may need to uninstall your current version first

Comment: Afterwards, you may run into this issue: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71359062/iproxy-cannot-be-opened-because-the-developer-cannot-be-verified

Answer (score 2):

Just download that specific flutter version from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases). and just set the flutter version in your editor and try to run it will run that specific flutter version but make sure you can't run that with terminal commands. So you need to handle all commands from the Tools option.

[set flutter version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3EtR.png)

[Must Run commands from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8hKR.png)

Comment: Hey Vishal, thanks for your contribution, however that's the third option on my list. The disadvantage is it's also the slowest, since each file would be more than 1GB. Highly not recommended