# “iproxy” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified

Tags: flutter

Today I connect the use cable to debug the flutter app in mac book pro with m1 chip, when I started the debugging process in Android Studio `Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2`, the system tell me error:

```
“iproxy” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
```

this is the full UI:

[image]

when I tried to resolved it in System Preferences > Security & Privacy set to allow idevice_id, and I did not found the setting. I am using mac book pro with M1 chip, the OS version is macOS Monterey 12.2.1 .

Comment: Same problem with M2 Macbook Air.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

I finally found this could fix, first switch to the folder of flutter(change the path to your own flutter path):

```
cd FLUTTER SDK DIRECTORY/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/usbmuxd
```

then execute this command:

```
sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine iproxy
```

Comment: Delete /flutter/bin/cache/artifact directory worked for me. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42969#issuecomment-568303471

Comment: Only add Background Modes from Singing & Capabilities of Xcode and ensure check Background Fetch and Background processing

Comment: Works on my side, thank you I give +1 so it makes 100likes :D

Comment: `flutter doctor --verbose` reveals your flutter SDK directory

Comment: Here's a copy-pasteable one-liner to fix the issue for your current flutter folder, no matter which version you are on: `sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine "$(echo "$(dirname "$(dirname "$(realpath "$(which flutter)")")")/bin/cache/artifacts/usbmuxd/iproxy")"`

Comment: if you have fvm - then `iproxy` should be here -> `cd ~/fvm/default/bin/cache/artifacts/usbmuxd/`
then
`sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine iproxy`

Answer (score 123):

for me it just helps by opening mac preferences -> security and privacy and you should see appeared checkbox with "Allow iproxy to smth..."

[image]

Comment: I don't see that button (and associated label) on that window/view.

Comment: tried this but every time flutter run, it still asking for iproxy permission

Comment: Works on Ventura, thanks

Answer (score 28):

Open System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Click Allow Anyway (Circled in the screenshot) -> Click Cancel on the dialog “iproxy” cannot be opened because"..
Click "Open" if another dialog appears. The dialog won't appear again.[image: Security & Privacy Settings]

Answer (score 20):

Exactly, what worked for me:
Simply,

1. Go to **flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/usbmuxd**
2. Tap on "iproxy" using  " ⌘ + touchpad ".

[image]

3. Select "open" from the popup, it will open terminal and save settings on your mac for this file.

[image]

4. Perfect! You are good to go now. Just close your ide and run agin the app.

Comment: Geeze Apple.  Way to lock everything down. Yes it's secure so I can't complain.  But they definitely shouldn't be doing it to developers like this. They should have "developer mode" where you can run untrusted stuff.  Just my opinion. I love apple hardware but their software team is something else!

Answer (score 11):

You can simply go to the file in `Finder` and crtl + right click, than choose open, it will add an exception for this file and will execute next time without this warning. Normally located in this path:

```
../flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/usbmuxd/iproxy
```

Comment: If you installed flutter using the suggested paths on flutter.io then `../` will be `~/development/`. If this is the case, then on Mac you can find `iproxy` in finder using the following terminal command $`open ~/development/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/usbmuxd/` or in finder press cmd+shift+g and paste `~/development/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/usbmuxd/`

Answer (score 11):

Just go to

> Settings -> Privacy & Security - then, scroll down, then click `Allow anyway` button.

Answer (score 5):

Step 1 : Run Debug Mode

Step 2 : Go to Settings -> Privacy & Security
Wait for a proxy alert

Step 3 : Click on Allow Anyway button for a successful debug

Answer (score 4):

If installed via brew, Flutter (and iproxy) change folders when new version is installed (eg. `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.3.7/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/usbmuxd/iproxy`).

I find this one liner useful:

```
 find /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter -iname "iproxy" -exec xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 3):

The file is located inside `flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/usbmuxd`. Go there from Finder, Control-click on the file and choose Open from the opened context menu. Mac will notify that opening this file will add it into exception from security settings. Click open and it should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well, I believe it was because I had configured my device for a wireless connection and had plugged it in. I am unsure why this caused an issue.

Solved by unplugging my iPhone from my Mac, and running in debug mode again.