# Flutter iOS app deployment not working from Android Studio BUT deploys from XCode without any issue

Tags: xcode, flutter

My flutter doctor shows no issues. But I have recently setup everything on a new computer and having this issue. When I try to run the app on my physical iOS device, I get the following errors:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-06-27 15:52:23.378 xcodebuild[39843:273853] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-06-27 15:52:23.378 xcodebuild[39843:273853] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
            { id:00008101-001C758A1440001E }

        The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.

        Available destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
            { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00006001-001C614A0C45801E }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:18BCE07F-0639-45DC-A88C-C394398F703F, OS:15.5, name:iPad (9th generation) }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AFE97147-0392-40D5-9D2D-22C5E4F0C58A, OS:15.5, name:iPad Air (5th generation) }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BE130D0D-FB0F-4536-851A-E37E22BB3414, OS:15.5, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A3FAD2AF-13E9-4DD9-ADCB-7F3A07E1A91F, OS:15.5, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:32C46EAD-B43D-478A-BCBC-1873F5B88272, OS:15.5, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:33089D75-ADA6-4FCF-8548-AE24F46CC662, OS:15.5, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:57A073B1-D6CF-4AB6-A8A0-063663563F01, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 8 }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:9B90E33E-9157-4C21-8E13-A513138B531C, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:07BDE9FF-DBFF-4086-A317-FBEDED3F04C0, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 11 }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3E6B4A9D-303B-4FD3-9877-55E4F6C7F558, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6C7D7DF9-BCA6-40FF-881B-029EEC3AC1B4, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EF2386F4-B2DB-498A-966E-729BD351D94D, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0B535439-DFE7-4D33-81B1-A5CAD386838B, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B9C0F68C-5873-4BB0-B457-CAE2436B5515, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4AE57F6F-A6EE-492B-8582-EEFC59544827, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 mini }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CB0081A2-CABF-4739-A522-665A0EDF24B8, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6BD837CD-FA08-46A5-BE84-53DEB9C65C65, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2875975C-C34D-450A-9520-7C45C3FD7F06, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:9D077924-19B8-4D57-86BB-60F83C9BE149, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 mini }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0370028B-E235-441C-9B90-AFD349F904F5, OS:15.5, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3FCD98F1-730D-4D55-9E19-4AFC0F0F20E7, OS:15.5, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }

        Ineligible destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
            { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
            { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
            { platform:iOS, id:00008101-001C758A1440001E, name:DMan, error:Device is busy (Preparing the watch for development via DMan) }

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Building a deployable iOS app requires a selected Development Team with a 
Provisioning Profile. Please ensure that a Development Team is selected by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected under Signing & Capabilities > Team. 
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again

For more information, please visit:
  https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Error launching application on DMan.
```

But when I open the workspace and run the app from there, it loads perfectly fine. I have the development team setup for all modes, release, debug etc.

Has anyone else faced this issue? What could be missing from my setup?

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone else has relentlessly tried to fix the same issue but was unable to. Just try the steps here once again!

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices

Re-running the steps here has solved my issue.

You may also get an "iProxy error' pop-up when running on your device for the first time. But check this thread for an answer to that problem: [“iproxy” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71359062/iproxy-cannot-be-opened-because-the-developer-cannot-be-verified)