# Flutter iOS Developing On a Physical Device --host-vmservice-port message

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, simulator

I'm trying to develop my flutter app with a physical (iOS) device plugged in, to access hot reload and hot restart. (via `flutter run`)

I am able to run the app with my device with `flutter run` however, I get the logs:

```
If you do NOT see the Flutter application running, it might have crashed. The device logs (e.g. from adb or XCode) might have more details.
If you do see the Flutter application running on the device, try re-running with --host-vmservice-port to use a specific port known to be available.
```

This prohibits me from accessing the developer tools in the console.

Is there a way to find the `--host-vmservice-port` of the physical device?

Answer (score 1):

Found out that this was because my system user didn't have read/write permissions for the `/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/usbmuxd/iproxy` file.

Enabled it following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71359062/iproxy-cannot-be-opened-because-the-developer-cannot-be-verified), and now I'm able to successfully debug and hot reload with a physical device ✔️