# Flutter IOS build - Groovin-widget error during building for device

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter, dart

I'm running flutter ios build post null-safety migration with following flutter version V3.13.2 & dart version v3.1.0

once Xcode build is completed , facing below error which exits

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode):
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/groovin_widgets-3.1.0/lib/src/widgets/groovin
_list_tile.dart:841:10: Error: Expected 2 type arguments.


Encountered error while building for device.
```

need suggestion if i need to update that widget to any specific version or how to go about it ?

issue line in package - groovin_list_tile.dart

```
class _GroovinListTile extends RenderObjectWidget
    **with SlottedMultiChildRenderObjectWidgetMixin<_ListTileSlot> {**
  const _GroovinListTile({
    this.leading,
    required this.title,
    this.subtitle,
    this.trailing,
    required this.isThreeLine,
    required this.isDense,
    required this.visualDensity,
    required this.textDirection,
    required this.titleBaselineType,
    required this.horizontalTitleGap,
    required this.minVerticalPadding,
    required this.minLeadingWidth,
    this.subtitleBaselineType,
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify local Flutter version (e.g. an older release)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866692/how-to-specify-local-flutter-version-e-g-an-older-release)